# scrape info from nested div excel vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract the start date from the following, but my code cant seem to see the 'nested" div "daysTips" any help would be great. Thank you.

**HTML Screen Shot:**
[image]

```
Sub warranty2()

Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x280-type-20kf-20ke/20ke/20kes5sd09/pc0x5yhz/warranty"

Do
 DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set Doc = IE.document
Set elements = Doc.getElementsByClassName("daysTips")

For i = 0 To elements.Length - 1
 Sheet1.Range("G" & (i + 1)) = elements(i).innerText
Next i

IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: If I use wget commanline to store an url it does not have `daysTips` element anywhere. Is it a dynamic runtime element or removed from the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the click first on the down chevron

[image]

HTML:

[image]

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x280-type-20kf-20ke/20ke/20kes5sd09/pc0x5yhz/warranty"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        IE.document.querySelector(".icon.icon-s-down").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Debug.Print IE.document.querySelector(".daysTips span").innerText
        .Quit 
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You beauty! thank you soooo much, that's been bugging me for ages. Really appreciate your input.

Comment: It was a cool problem. Took me a moment to realise what was going on with the element in question!